# pthreads with Swift 2 and Quality of Service

Tags: swift, pthreads

I’m playing around with pthreads and Quality of Service. Naturally, I thought the best way to do so would be in an Xcode Playground.

The following ran perfectly.

```
var user_interactive_thread: pthread_t = nil

pthread_create(&user_interactive_thread, nil, { (x:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) in
    print("pthread ran")

    return nil
}, nil)
```

But then I tried to add the QoS attribute:

```
var user_interactive_thread: pthread_t = nil
var user_interactive_qos_attr: pthread_attr_t

pthread_attr_init(&user_interactive_qos_attr)
pthread_attr_set_qos_class_np(&user_interactive_qos_attr, QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)

pthread_create(&user_interactive_thread, &user_interactive_qos_attr, { (x:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) in
    print("User interactive pthread")

    return nil
}, nil)
```

But I got the following compiler error(s):

```
Playground execution failed: /var/folders/fv/m8h6cz5n7xx7bwb7qxppx2qc0000gn/T/./lldb/29864/playground7.swift:16:42: error: address of variable 'user_interactive_qos_attr' taken before it is initialized
pthread_create(&user_interactive_thread, &user_interactive_qos_attr, { (x:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) in
                                         ^
/var/folders/fv/m8h6cz5n7xx7bwb7qxppx2qc0000gn/T/./lldb/29864/playground7.swift:11:5: note: variable defined here
var user_interactive_qos_attr: pthread_attr_t
    ^
/var/folders/fv/m8h6cz5n7xx7bwb7qxppx2qc0000gn/T/./lldb/29864/playground7.swift:14:31: error: address of variable 'user_interactive_qos_attr' taken before it is initialized
pthread_attr_set_qos_class_np(&user_interactive_qos_attr, QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)
                              ^
/var/folders/fv/m8h6cz5n7xx7bwb7qxppx2qc0000gn/T/./lldb/29864/playground7.swift:11:5: note: variable defined here
var user_interactive_qos_attr: pthread_attr_t
    ^
/var/folders/fv/m8h6cz5n7xx7bwb7qxppx2qc0000gn/T/./lldb/29864/playground7.swift:13:19: error: address of variable 'user_interactive_qos_attr' taken before it is initialized
pthread_attr_init(&user_interactive_qos_attr)
                  ^
/var/folders/fv/m8h6cz5n7xx7bwb7qxppx2qc0000gn/T/./lldb/29864/playground7.swift:11:5: note: variable defined here
var user_interactive_qos_attr: pthread_attr_t
    ^
```

This is helpful and you can obviously see where I’ve gone wrong. But when I try to set `user_interactive_qos_attr` to nil initially, I get the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: /var/folders/fv/m8h6cz5n7xx7bwb7qxppx2qc0000gn/T/./lldb/29864/playground8.swift:11:49: error: nil cannot initialize specified type 'pthread_attr_t' (aka '_opaque_pthread_attr_t')
var user_interactive_qos_attr: pthread_attr_t = nil
                                                ^
```

Then I turned to optionals. This removed all compiler errors but then a run time error occurred when trying to unwrap the nil optional.

Is there something I’m doing wrong? Or is pthreads not fully supported in Swift 2?

Answer (score 1):

If someone who’s better equipped with pthreads/Swift could double check:

This seems to work perfectly:

```
var return_value: Int32 = 0

var user_interactive_thread = pthread_t()
var user_interactive_qos_attr = pthread_attr_t()

return_value = pthread_attr_init(&user_interactive_qos_attr)
return_value = pthread_attr_set_qos_class_np(&user_interactive_qos_attr, QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)

return_value = pthread_create(&user_interactive_thread, &user_interactive_qos_attr, { (x:UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) in
    print("User interactive pthread")

    return nil
}, nil)
```

With or without the `return_value` obviously.

It doesn’t seem like it should work though. It seems like I’m cheating the initialiser.

Comment: Variables in Swift must be initialized before being used, even if passed as in-out argument to another function. The compiler does not know that `pthread_attr_set_qos_class_np()` will initialize the variable. `pthread_attr_t()` is a default initializer setting all struct members to zero. – So this is the correct solution, why do you think that it should not work or is cheating?

Comment: Yeah I understand why I was getting the errors. It seems strange to me because I am used to pthreads using C++, where there was no need to set the variable before calling `pthread_create` (if I remember correctly). I guess it’s just one of the nice things about having a much more aware compiler